# Active MQ - incorporate the configuration broker

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

```
<bean id="myTopic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <property name="physicalName" value="feed.topic" />
</bean>

<bean id="myConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>

<bean id="myJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="myTopic" />
</bean>

<bean id="sender" class="com.feed.publish.PublishMessages">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="myJmsTemplate" />
</bean>
```

I have the above set up using the spring framework that allows me to publish messages to a queue. However, if the activemq instance is terminated mid process, I would like it to write to disk/file the messages until a connection can be reestablished. I have found sample code off of the website of activemq however I am unsure how I integrate this in to my current setup

```
<amq:broker useJmx="true" persistent="true" brokerName="localhost">
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:kahaPersistenceAdapter directory="activemq-data"
            maxDataFileLength="33554432" />
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://localhost" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

Can someone please tell me how I go about merging these two styles? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the AMQ persistenceAdapter configuration is to allow the **AMQ Broker** to persist messages to disk, **not the client**.  If the broker connection is terminated, your client code should catch the exception, write the messages to disk and provide a means to replay them at a later time.

along these lines, I generally use Apache Camel's [exception handling](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) and [file](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) components to handle these type of scenarios...